# Enable register_globals in PHP 5.6

Tags: php

I have a website that uses register_globals. My local php version is 5.6. I know that register_globals is DEPRECATED since PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED in PHP 5.4. But i have to make it work on PHP 5.6, Is there any way to make it work? And is there any problem when i develop on PHP 5.6 and deploy it to production which is use PHP 5.2? Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: Well... Using PHP 5.6 in the development process may lead to use of PHP functionality that does not exists on PHP 5.2. You will face this when you deploy it on the server and you will have to invest extra time on this problematic code. You can possibly mimic the behavior of register_globals by writing a custom function that makes the same.

Comment: Read this artical http://pageconfig.com/post/register_globals-is-back-php-implementation

Comment: Even though there is a way to do it: You really shouldn't.

Comment: @rolice i already create 1 custom php file. Which is contents some function to call / recognize the variable global. And the problem was solved. But, that i'm thingking is, when i develop website contents on php5.6 and then deploy it to production which is use php 5.2, is there any error will happen because of the diffrent version with php?

Comment: @user3661054, the code will be run smoothly if you write it compatible with PHP 5.2, i.e. if all the functions are present and working in PHP 5.2 it will work. But mostly of my experience when you develop on specific PHP version you check if tasks are completed on that version, so when you deploy your code on older PHP version (PHP 5.2 your case) all new features you might have used on PHP 5.6 will not be available and it will throw errors, notices, warnings and so on. The opposite is safer - older PHP code should work on new versions - outdated functionality is first deprecated and then cut..

Comment: I don't want to promote this technique AT ALL, because DONT DO THIS IF YOU WANT A SECURE WEBSITE, but: http://blog.le-vert.net/?p=92

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to enable as feature of PHP, but I have developed a library to emulate `register_globals`.

- https://github.com/gongo/merciful-polluter
- https://packagist.org/packages/gongo/merciful-polluter

merciful_polluter emulate `register_globals` and `magic_quotes_gpc` (Both were removed in PHP 5.4)

```
<?php
/**
 * example.com/?foo=3&bar=12
 */

(new Gongo\MercifulPolluter\Requst)->pollute();

global $foo, $bar;
var_dump($foo, $bar);

/**
 * int(3)
 * int(12)
 */
```

Support PHP versions are 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0.

**CAUTION: This library is just a emulator**